# window.deviceorientation does not working in safari browser

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-safari, device-orientation

i want to fire device orientation event for mobiles using JavaScript, 
my code is worked fine in chrome , but  it doesn't work in safari

```
if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {
    window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', eventData => {
      // gamma: Tilting the device from left to right. Tilting the device to the right will result in a positive value.
      const tiltLR = eventData.gamma;
      // beta: Tilting the device from the front to the back. Tilting the device to the front will result in a positive value.
      const tiltFB = eventData.beta;
      // alpha: The direction the compass of the device aims to in degrees.
      const dir = eventData.alpha;
      // Call the function to use the data on the page.
      deviceOrientationHandler(tiltLR, tiltFB, dir);
    }, false);
}
```